# SQL Materialized views in CakePHP 4 and PostGreSQL

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I just hit an interesting wall. We are in the process of developing a pretty reasonable sized application that has a ton of historical data. The plan is to use materialized views and do nightly/weekly refreshes as applicable to help reduce the impact on the server for large data set reports.

I know that in Cake 2, I could just define a new view by creating the appropriate model and the running with it. I could even bake the model as a starting point.

However, with Cake 4, I am getting an error when I try to use it. Specifically the error that gets raised is:
“Cannot describe v_12month_summary. It has 0 columns.”
This happens whether I bake, or manually create the entity and table model files.

Is there a way to use materialized, or even regular views, with CakePHP 4? Essentially, I would like to be able to:

`$yearSummary = $this->fetchTable('V12monthSummary')->find()->where(['month'=>6,'year'=>2021'])`

Comment: IIRC still only regular views are supported as far as finding and introspecting the schema goes. You might want to bring up **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10238** again as a feature request.

Comment: OK thanks. I will go read and check what they have to say